# (Errno 22) invalid argument when trying to run a python program from a bat file

Tags: python, batch-file, errno

I'm following this exactly but it is not working https://youtu.be/qHcHUHF_Qfo?t=438

I type the location in the run window:

```
C:\Users\Zachary lastName\mypythonscripts\hello.py
```

I get error message:

> can't open file 'c:\users"Zachary': [Errno 22] invalid argument

The bat file is:

```
@py C:\Users\Zachary lastName\mypythonscripts\hello.py %*

@pause
```

I've searched everywhere and can't find an answer, I also edited the path environment variable so I can just type the name of the program in the run window but again I get the error. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enclose the path name in quotes because the space means a new argument is expected, and it's not finding the file:

```
@py "C:\Users\Zachary lastName\mypythonscripts\hello.py" %*
@pause
```

Now the file path should not interfere. Usernames with spaces can become a problem for paths as their space can cause issues. Just enclose it in quotes to convert to string.

Comment: Thank you, this definitely helped, but it still doesnt run the file because my python files are now no longer working, when I click on a python file it says the file has no program associated with it, not sure what happened.

Comment: Are you clicking on the python file or the batch file? @theeinfamousone

Comment: either one, now when I click on any of my python program I get the error that no program is associated with the file, if I right click on it, and look at properties it says the .py files open with unknown application.

Comment: Then you have accidentally uninstalled Python? It works perfectly on my system. Check file associations

Comment: I got it! I had trouble finding where python 3 had installed to, I found it and had my .py files default open with python 3 now, and with your previous suggestion everything is working now, thank you!!

Comment: No problem; glad to help!